# How to substract time in mysql and display in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Using mySql:

Start time = current time
Oldtime = current time - 6 hours

I was able to get the current time and display it but can not get/substract the time 6 hours before the initial/current time and store it in a variable so I can display it using PHP.

```
   currenttime = SELECT CURTIME()
result = mysqli_query(con,currenttime)
while(row = mysqli_fetch_array(result)) {
starttime = row[CURTIME()]

echo starttime//<==works till here

timebefore = SELECT SUBTIME('starttime',06:00:00')
```

I checked the function SUBTIME(EXPR1,EXPR2) in mySql command prompt and it works fine but cannot get it inside the PHP script.

Please help.

Comment: This is not remotely syntactically valid PHP code, it cannot work. [PHP Tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php)

Comment: Instructions for writing syntactically valid code are in the PHP tutorial that I referred you to. You cannot expect people here to teach you PHP. Read the FAQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how I ended up doing it in the end:

date("H:i:s",mktime(date("H")-$number,date("i"),date("s"), 0, 0,0));

There could be many different ways of doing it but I was able to achieve what I wanted in this way.

My PHP version is 5.3.27 but I wasn't able to use the object oriented approach.

Did not think I needed to include any libraries or anything.

Oh well, hope my answer helps others who are new like me and got stuck with something similar and won't have to go through some vague, useless instructions from some users.

Cheers.